# php and js // csv to tables (with extras) to csv

Tags: php, javascript, csv

I'm trying to find something already made (hopefully) or some tips on where to start, but what I need to accomplish is take an existing csv file, load it into a html table, be able to edit it, or add duplicate rows, then save my edited version as a new csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single most important thing is: Don't try to parse the file yourself! There are builtin functions for csv handling in PHP. The example in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) can be easily altered to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like something you could do through the [Google Docs Spreadsheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/overview.html).